# Javascript image error issue

Tags: javascript, error-handling, winjs

I have a winjs application in which it shows list of images.
i created the image via code using

```
 var image = document.createElement("img");
```

and set the source like

```
 image.setAttribute("src", self._viewModel._metadata.imageUrl);
```

and in some cases these the image urls are expired.In those case i need to update the image source by querying the api and update the results.

```
image.addEventListener("error", self._onError(image), true);
```

I have added a listener to the image tag to get the error and to replace the source.

But the event fires for all images not only for urls expired image but for properly working item also.

to the event handler I passed the image so that i can set the src after getting the new url from service.
Is there any way to limit this event to be fired to only images having problem(i mean the url expired images).

I am working with an xbox application so the environment is windows explores.

Any option to know how the error occurred in the event handler.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `image.src = self._viewModel._metadata.imageUrl;` ? Do share a demo to play with!

Comment: I tried image.src = self._viewModel._metadata.imageUrl but still the same behavior firing error event for all images

Comment: Tried logging out what self._viewModel... is

Comment: @ Balint the url is a valid one but since it is expired it wont display the image for eg:http://da5.rbmbtnx.net/v3/RBTV/pd/FO-1MKA4ZYYN2111/im:i:c_fill,h_220,w_440/defiance_display_landscape.jpg/?__token__=exp=1459412937~acl=/v3/RBTV/pd/FO-1MKA4ZYYN2111*~hmac=ff1705239b5f3e98bde7c16cf03fd78f851b416c0f5adbb299365c00c29933c9

Comment: @Joseph, Can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: +1 on sharing a sample. @Joseph can you give us a code sample on how the whole cycle through images looks like?